# Einstein action as a functional of the tetrad (first order formulation of gravity)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravity, quantum-gravity, differential-geometry

Let the Einstein-Hilbert action be rewritten as a functional of the tetrad $e$ (units shall be set to $1$) such that
$S_{EH}(e)=\int \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{IJKL}~e^I\wedge e^J\wedge F^{KL}(\omega(e))$, where $\epsilon$ is the Levi-Civta-symbol as usual, $F$ is the curvature of the spin connection $\omega$ and $I,J,K,L$ denote internal indices, indicating that the object carries a rep. of the Lorentz group.
How do I get back to the usual action $S_{EH}(g)=\int~d^4x\sqrt{-g}R$? I am trying to figure it out using identities but can't finish till the end. Could anybody give a little more detailed account, please? Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could include a little more detail about what you have already done and where you are stuck?

Comment: Well, $S_{EH}(e)=\int \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{IJKL}~e^I\wedge e^J\wedge F^{KL}(\omega(e))~=~\int \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{IJKL} e_{\alpha}^I e_{\beta}^J F_{\gamma\delta}^{K L} dx^{\alpha}\wedge dx^{\beta} \wedge dx^{\gamma} \wedge dx^{\delta}~=~\int 4!\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{IJKL} e_{\alpha}^I e_{\beta}^J F_{\gamma\delta}^{K L}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}d^{4}x$. From the other side I know $S_{EH}(g)~=~\int~d^4x\sqrt{-g}R~=~\int d^4x\sqrt{-g} R_{\mu\nu} g^{\mu\nu}~=~\int d^4x e e^{\mu}_I e^{\nu~I}R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}e^{\rho}_J e^{\sigma~J}~=~\int d^4x e e^{\mu}_I e^{\rho}_J F^{IJ}_{\mu\rho}$.

Comment: With which trick can I tie both ends together?

Comment: What is a relationship between the spin-connection and the Riemann tensor?

Comment: The curvature is $F^{IJ}=d\omega^{I J}+ \omega^{I}_{K}\wedge \omega^{K J}$, where the spin and Levi-Civita connections are related as $\omega^{I}_{\mu~J}=e^{I}_{\nu}\nabla_{\mu}e^{\nu}_{J}$. Cartan's first structure equation is $d_{\omega}e^I=0$, where $d_{\omega}$ is the $\omega$-twisted differential. Cartan's second structure equation is $F^{I J}_{\mu\nu}=e^{I\rho}e^{J\sigma}R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$.

Comment: So the question is, how do I get from $\int 4!\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{IJKL} e_{\alpha}^I e_{\beta}^J F_{\gamma\delta}^{K L}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}d^{4}x$ to $\int d^4x e e^{\mu}_I e^{\rho}_J F^{IJ}_{\mu\rho}$?

Comment: Well, now you're almost there.  Figure out a way to simplify $\epsilon_{IJKL}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}e_{\alpha}^{I}e_{\beta}^{J}$

Comment: @Jerry. My problem is not the algebraic manipulation but that I am lacking the identities for the epsilon symbols.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Levi-Civita symbol in curved space-time, $\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}$ ,is defined as :

$$\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} = e~ \epsilon^{I'J'K'L'} e_{I'}^\alpha e_{J'}^\beta e_{K'}^\gamma e_{L'}^\delta,$$

where $\epsilon^{I'J'K'L'}$ is the standard Levi-Civita symbol (flat spacetime).

The presence of the $e$  is because $\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}$ has to transform as a tensor.

You could then use the  properties of the standard Levi-Civita symbol. For instance, the product $\epsilon^{I'J'K'L'} \epsilon_{IJKL}$ could be obtained as a determinant of the matrix of Kronecker delta symbols $\delta^M_N $. The product equals $1$ if $I'J'K'L'$ is a even permutation of $IJKL$, and $-1$ if $I'J'K'L'$ is a odd permutation of $IJKL$, $0$ in other cases.

And you are going to use the fact that the matrix $e_I^\alpha$ and $e_\beta^J$, are inverse matrix.

[EDIT]
Here is the complete calculus:

\begin{align}
S_{EH}(g)&=\int\sqrt{-g}R\,\mathrm{d}^4x\\
&=\int \sqrt{-g} R_{\mu\nu} g^{\mu\nu}\,\mathrm{d}^4x\\
&=\int e\, e^{\mu}_I e^{\nu~I}R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}e^{\rho}_J e^{\sigma~J}\,\mathrm{d}^4x\\
&=\int e\, e^{\mu}_I e^{\rho}_J F^{IJ}_{\mu\rho}\,\mathrm{d}^4x
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
S_{EH}(e)&=\int \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{IJKL}~e^I\wedge e^J\wedge F^{KL}(\omega(e))\\
&=~\int \frac{1}{2}~\epsilon_{IJKL}~ e_{\alpha}^I \,\mathrm{d}x^{\alpha} \wedge  e_{\beta}^J   \,\mathrm{d}x^{\beta} \wedge (\frac{1}{2} F_{\gamma\delta}^{K L}  \wedge \,\mathrm{d}x^{\gamma} \wedge \,\mathrm{d}x^{\delta})\\
&=~\int \frac{1}{4}~\epsilon_{IJKL}~ e_{\alpha}^I~ e_{\beta}^J ~F_{\gamma\delta}^{K L} \,\mathrm{d}x^{\alpha}\wedge \,\mathrm{d}x^{\beta} \wedge \,\mathrm{d}x^{\gamma} \wedge \,\mathrm{d}x^{\delta}\\
&=~\int \frac{1}{4}\epsilon_{IJKL}~ \epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}~e_{\alpha}^I ~e_{\beta}^J ~F_{\gamma\delta}^{K L}\,\mathrm{d}^{4}x\\
&=~\int e\frac{1}{4}~\epsilon_{IJKL} ~\epsilon^{I'J'K'L'} ~e_{I'}^\alpha ~e_{J'}^\beta ~e_{K'}^\gamma ~e_{L'}^\delta ~e_{\alpha}^I ~e_{\beta}^J ~F_{\gamma\delta}^{K L}\,\mathrm{d}^{4}x\\
&=~\int e \frac{1}{4}~\epsilon_{IJKL} ~\epsilon^{I'J'K'L'} ~\delta_{I'}^I  ~\delta_{J'}^J ~e_{K'}^\gamma ~e_{L'}^\delta ~F_{\gamma\delta}^{K L}\,\mathrm{d}^{4}x\\
&=~\int e \frac{1}{4}~\epsilon_{IJKL} ~\epsilon^{IJK'L'}  ~e_{K'}^\gamma ~e_{L'}^\delta ~F_{\gamma\delta}^{K L}\,\mathrm{d}^{4}x\\
&=~\int e \frac{1}{4} ~2 ~(\delta_{K}^L \delta_{K'}^{L'} - \delta_{K}^{L'} \delta_{K'}^L)~  e_{K'}^\gamma ~e_{L'}^\delta ~F_{\gamma\delta}^{K L}\,\mathrm{d}^{4}x\\
&=~\int ~e ~\frac{1}{4} 2*2~(\delta_{K}^L \delta_{K'}^{L'})~  e_{K'}^\gamma ~e_{L'}^\delta ~F_{\gamma\delta}^{K L}\,\mathrm{d}^{4}x\\
&=~\int ~e  ~e_{K}^\gamma ~e_{L}^\delta ~F_{\gamma\delta}^{K L}\,\mathrm{d}^{4}x
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Trimok. I have done the computation but am ending up with a factor 4 to much. I have used http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#equation_8 together with the identity that you wrote down. It could be that the 4! that I wrote in the question is wrong.

Comment: Are you ending up with a factor $4$ too much, or a factor $4!$ too much ?

Comment: @Hamurabi : I think your $4!$ term is not correct. The correct equation is  $ dx^{\alpha}\wedge dx^{\beta} \wedge dx^{\gamma} \wedge dx^{\delta} = \epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} d^4x$

Comment: @Hamurabi : I made an EDIT in the answer, with the complete calculus

Comment: ah. good. thank you. i forgot the $1/2$ in front of the $F_{\mu\nu}$ as usual :)

Comment: Could it be, that this formula 8 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#equation_8 is not completely correct in the sense that one has to swap the $(n-k)!$ from the formula in the middle over to the other formula on the right?

Comment: No, it is correct. The notation $$\large \delta_{i_{k+1}....i_n}^{j_{k+1}....j_n}$$ means that all the antisymmetric possibilities of the $\delta$ functions are considered, each with the weight $1$. The total weight is $(n-k)!$ because there are $(n-k)!$ terms. 

But the notation $$\large \delta_{[i_{k+1}}^{j_{k+1}}...\delta_{i_{n}]}^{j_{n}}$$ means that all the antisymmetric possibilities of the $\delta$ functions are considered, but each with the weight $\frac{1}{(n-k)!}$, so that the total weight is $1$.

Comment: So, the 2 quantities are proportionnal, that is  : 
$$\large  \delta_{i_{k+1}....i_n}^{j_{k+1}....j_n} = (n-k)! ~ \delta_{[i_{k+1}}^{j_{k+1}}...\delta_{i_{n}]}^{j_{n}}$$